# Sending intermediary responses on API call

Tags: node.js, api, server, backend

I'm not sure how to achieve this behavior from our server:

- Backend behavior

1. client sends request
2. server responds in `<1s` with an intermediary response - something like `step 1/2`
3. server start performing the computation
4. when done, server sends back the finalized task - `step 2/2 finished`

- Frontend behavior

1. send request
2. act on the intermediary step being finished - purpose of this: the entire flow is more engaging
3. act on the request being step

I would like to all this by calling only one API endpoint. Is this possible?

Comment: Just found `res.write()` - would this solve it?

Comment: You shouldn't really "stream" a HTTP response like this over a long period to achieve this task, it wouldn't be robust and it would also be hard to parse. HTTP requests are not resilient to bad connections and any server along the hops could terminate it before its done. What are you looking for are the parts of the browser standard lib that are designed for this, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events or plain websockets

Comment: https://ably.com/topic/websockets-vs-http may interest you